# FB Asking for Permissions When Click on Open Graph Activity Feed Link?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am building a facebook web application. I have successfully posted an open graph activity to a test user's timeline. Now, when logged in as that same user, and I view that activity in my timeline, then click on the link to go view that URL associated with the activity, it is asking me again for permissions. Specifically it is asking for "location" information and "Manage your events".

Note this is after the user already authorized the app with these permissions (user_about_me,publish_stream,friends_about_me,email,publish_actions).

So why would it be asking for more permissions, just to view a link? Also note that it asks every time I click on that link...not just the first.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance,
Chad

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Authenticated Referrals must be disabled on your Application permissions in Facebook developers

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals

> "Authenticated referrals is a new feature that ensures all referral traffic from Facebook to your application is already connected to Facebook. Visitors arriving to your app will be automatically logged in and, if necessary, be prompted for any permissions you have requested."